# handling mutliple inputs using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I have react hooks section in which  user can edit input fields, there are hundreds of inputs that is why I need to use redux (newbie to redux though),

Live demo on codesandbox: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/inputs-fo6mb?file=/src/Components/Settings.js)

so far I have this

```
const initialState = {
  firstName: "Kunta ",
  lastName: "Kinte"
};

const detailsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { name, value } = action;

  return { ...state, [name]: value };
};

export default detailsReducer;
```

and here is setting js where I have input fields

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Details from "./Details";
import DetailsReducer from "../Reducer/DetailsReducer";

const Settings = () => {
  const fields = useSelector((state) => state.DetailsReducer);
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Edit </h1>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="inputs">
            <label htmlfor="fname">First name:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="fname"
              name="fname"
              value={state}
              onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
            />
            <label htmlfor="lname" />
            Last name:
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)} />
          </div>
          <Details />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

Expected results: Just when the user types in inputs eg first name it should change the value of the first name in the details component.

I am strugling to get this working can some please help?

Comment: I dont see any code rode in relation to updating the redux state using dispatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked your CodeSandbox and got a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inputs-forked-51hfu)

Some notes on what I did to get it working.

1. Added `redux` package which is the core redux functionality. This is what lets you create a redux store. Check out the docs [here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started).
2. Create `store` with the `DetailsReducer` using `createStore` from `redux` package. View this [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inputs-forked-51hfu?file=/src/Reducer/store.js).
3. Wrapped `App.js` with the `Provider` from `react-redux`. This is where you pass your redux `store`. Check docs [here](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#provider). This is important as it is the integration that allows react applications to work with redux. Without this, you can not use `useSelector` or `useDispatch` for example.
4. The next part is using the redux state values and dispatch on the input fields which you can see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inputs-forked-51hfu?file=/src/Components/Settings.js:504-670).

Just to be clear, the `redux` package is the core redux functionality. It is designed this way so redux can be used anywhere (like server side with NodeJS). The `react-redux` package is the react integration that makes consuming redux easy for react applications.

Side Note: Technically when you call dispatch you pass a `type` and the type controls how the reducer changes its state. Your example is so simple, there is no need for a type which is why in the example you see the type as an empty string. [Here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#basic-example) is an example of using the `type` though in the docs.